# Python make function available at shell launch

Tags: python

I would like to have the function below automatically defined every time I launch a python shell. What is the simplest way to do so?

```
import readline
def history(numLines=-1):
    total = readline.get_current_history_length()
    if numLines == -1:
        # default value prints everything
        numLines = total
    if numLines > 0:
        # range from n->end in order to incl. recent line
        for i in range(total - numLines, total):
            print(readline.get_history_item(i + 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in a file, and define [the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) with the path to that file. Per the docs:

> ##### PYTHONSTARTUP
>
> If this is the name of a readable file, the Python commands in that file are executed before the first prompt is displayed in interactive mode. The file is executed in the same namespace where interactive commands are executed so that objects defined or imported in it can be used without qualification in the interactive session. You can also change the prompts `sys.ps1` and `sys.ps2` and the hook `sys.__interactivehook__` in this file.

Comment: On many systems (esp. linux), `PYTHONSTARTUP` will be automatically set to `$HOME/.pythonrc.py`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Huh. Never seen that before (my recent experience has been on Alpine and Red Hat EL/CentOS), but I won't say it doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh - perhaps it's less common than I thought, then. On my current arch linux system, there's a script in `/etc/profile.d` that checks whether `$HOME/.pythonrc.py` exists, and if so sets `PYTHONSTARTUP` to that (or else `/etc/pythonrc.py`). I've used several other linux distros in the past, but I can't remember ever having to explicitly set `PYTHONSTARTUP`.